# "Who or where leave that to"

Tags: grammaticality, relative-clauses, parallelism

I was writing an email where I needed to return an item to a person who was not in the office the following day. So I came up with the following and I wonder if it's the the correct way of getting your point across or is grammatical at all?

> As I have one of your books and you are not in the office tomorrow, I was wondering **where or who to leave that to/with.**

Comment: Since you won't be in the office tomorrow, I'll just keep that book and give it to you when you get back.

Answer (score 4):

English doesn't have any "grammatically valid" construction for this particular conjunction.

Nor would it be particularly useful if there *was* such a construction. Partly because it would rarely be appropriate, but mainly because OP wondered *where to leave that* ***or*** *who to leave that with*. The only connection between those two possibilities are the repeated words *leave, to* and *that* (which should be *"it"* anyway). It simply isn't worth trying to fit both possibilities into a single construction to save a couple of words.

Also note that OP's suggestion already uses *"or"* to conjoin the first two variants *(where, who)*, but a slash to conjoin *to, with*. At best this would be inconsistent use of "pseudo-syntax" — but in this case it makes no sense, since you can't select *"to"* from the second pair to create a valid expression.

In such circumstances, normal practice would be to either completely rephrase and state both possibilities fully and grammatically...

> *I was wondering where to leave it, or who to leave it with. <sup>[1]</sup>*

...or (more common in speech) to simply enforce grammaticality for the *second* possibility only...

> *I was wondering where or who to leave it with.*

---

<sup>[1]</sup> Per comments below, *"who to leave it **to**"* is grammatically valid, but inappropriate in this case, since to *"leave [something] **to** [someone]"* means to transfer ownership - normally in the context of a will or bequest, to be actioned after one's death.

Comment: Thanks. As a side note, what is the difference between *leave it to* vs *leave it with*?

Comment: @Noah, _leave it to_ means to transfer ownership. If I leave a book to you it becomes your book. _Leave it with_ is temporary. If I leave a package with you, it is not yours, and it probably won't be appropriate for you to open the package.

Comment: @Old Pro: I'd have said *"leave it to"* means *"**bequest** it to"* (i.e. - ownership is transferred after your death). Unless what you're leaving is, for example, a *problem*, which you can leave to someone else by simply not dealing with it yourself. To be honest, I never even noticed that OP's second *"to"* could have been used in this way. It's not logically plausible in OP's context, but I guess I'd better edit to reflect that it's at least grammatically possible.

Comment: There is also _figuring out the solution is an exercise left to the reader_.

Comment: "to be actioned"?

Comment: @tchrist: Perfectly normal phrasing - [to be actioned](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22to+be+actioned%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) as in *to actually be enacted, as opposed to remaining a hypothetical intended future action*.

Comment: Sounds like dodgy business jargon to me. I hate business jargon. In fact, that’s just what the [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/1939) calls it.

Comment: @tchrist: I guess you're right. I can't follow your OED link - but thinking about it, it *is* essentially a business/legal/technical usage. I've used it that way for so long I never registered it might seem quirky to others.

Comment: The pupose of language is communication.

Comment: @Kris: Exactly - and once we agree the convention - along with Shakespeare's Juliet - that we'll [call something a rose](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_rose_by_any_other_name_would_smell_as_sweet), we know the immature form will be a ***rosebud***, not a ***sorebud***. The *structure* of language is biased towards consistent rules, even if it doesn't always apply. And one of those "rules" is we can usually convert a noun *(**an** action)* into a verb *(**to** action)* whenever this seems convenient.

Answer (score 2):

Is such detail necessary? Why not simply

> I have one of your books, but you are not in the office tomorrow, so how can I return it to you?

The trick is that you are asking for either a person to leave it *with* or a place to leave it *at*, so either you need to make each option explicit for clarity, along the lines of

> As I have one of your books and you are not in the office tomorrow, I was wondering where or with whom I should leave it.

or reword to avoid the prepositional vagaries of *leave*, e.g.

> As I have one of your books and you are not in the office tomorrow, is there a person or place I can entrust it to?

Comment: The Q. is just *to* or *with*.

Comment: @Kris, it looks like it's about the entire boldface phrase, not just to/with.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ***with***. There is no confusion about mistaking the *with* as belonging to both *where* and *who(m)* -- it will be correctly understood as attaching to the latter-mentioned.

Comment: As others have suggested, you may better rephrase it, though.